# how to return the length of the accumulator in reduce()

Tags: javascript, reduce

I an learning the **Reduce** Iterator in JavaScript I am trying to check the length of the accumulator, but it keeps returning a *TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*

Here is the array i am working with

```
var songs = [
{
    name: 'Smooth',
    artist: 'Santana featuring Rob Thomas',
    year: 1999,
    month: 10,
    day: 23,
    weeksAtNumberOne: 12,
    duration: '4:00',
},
{
    name: 'What a Girl Wants',
    artist: 'Christina Aguilera',
    year: 2000,
    month: 6,
    day: 15,
    weeksAtNumberOne: 2,
    duration: '3:20',
},
{
    name: 'I Knew I Loved You',
    artist: 'Savage Garden',
    year: 2000,
    month: 8,
    day: 29,
    weeksAtNumberOne: 4,
    duration: '4:10',
},
{
    name: 'Thank God I Found You',
    artist: 'Mariah Carey featuring Joe and 98 Degrees',
    year: 2000,
    month: 2,
    day: 19,
    weeksAtNumberOne: 2,
    duration: '4:17',
},
{
    name: 'Amazed',
    artist: 'Lonestar',
    year: 2000,
    month: 7,
    day: 4,
    weeksAtNumberOne: 2,
    duration: '4:00',
}]
```

The code

```
function summerCount(arr) {
return arr.reduce(function(init, next) {
    if ([6,7,8].includes(next.month)) {
        init.push(next.month);
    };
     return init.length;
}, [])};
```

If i return just **init**, it would return the array, but if i add the **.length** property, it would throw the TypeError.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know what reduce does? If the first invocation of your function receives an empty array and the first object and returns the length of the array, what does the second invocation receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the length of the accumulator only once all iterations are completed, not before, else the accumulator's value in the next iteration will be a number, rather than an array (and your code depends on the accumulator always being an *array*):

```js
var songs=[{name:'Smooth',artist:'Santana featuring Rob Thomas',year:1999,month:10,day:23,weeksAtNumberOne:12,duration:'4:00',},{name:'What a Girl Wants',artist:'Christina Aguilera',year:2000,month:6,day:15,weeksAtNumberOne:2,duration:'3:20',},{name:'I Knew I Loved You',artist:'Savage Garden',year:2000,month:8,day:29,weeksAtNumberOne:4,duration:'4:10',},{name:'Thank God I Found You',artist:'Mariah Carey featuring Joe and 98 Degrees',year:2000,month:2,day:19,weeksAtNumberOne:2,duration:'4:17',},{name:'Amazed',artist:'Lonestar',year:2000,month:7,day:4,weeksAtNumberOne:2,duration:'4:00',}]

function summerCount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(init, next) {
    if ([6, 7, 8].includes(next.month)) {
      init.push(next.month);
    };
    return init;
  }, []).length;
}
console.log(summerCount(songs));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `return init.length` inside `reduce()` that becomes the next accumulator. So the next time through reduce you try to look for the `length` property on an integer, which doesn't work (as you noticed).

If you want the length, just use reduce to return the array (`return init`) and look at the length of the array that's returned.

If you *just* want the count, then add to the accumulator as you go through and return the number:

```js
var songs = [{name: 'Smooth',artist: 'Santana featuring Rob Thomas',year: 1999,month: 10,day: 23,weeksAtNumberOne: 12,duration: '4:00',},{name: 'What a Girl Wants',artist: 'Christina Aguilera',year: 2000,month: 6,day: 15,weeksAtNumberOne: 2,duration: '3:20',},{name: 'I Knew I Loved You',artist: 'Savage Garden',year: 2000,month: 8,day: 29,weeksAtNumberOne: 4,duration: '4:10',},{name: 'Thank God I Found You',artist: 'Mariah Carey featuring Joe and 98 Degrees',year: 2000,month: 2,day: 19,weeksAtNumberOne: 2,duration: '4:17',},{name: 'Amazed',artist: 'Lonestar',year: 2000,month: 7,day: 4,weeksAtNumberOne: 2,duration: '4:00',}]

function summerCount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((init, next) => init + ([6,7,8].includes(next.month) ? 1 : 0)
  , 0)
}
console.log(summerCount(songs))
```